# Android: How to send message programmatically by using WhatsApp, WeChat?

Tags: android, sms, social-networking

How to use messaging in android application by using **WhatsApp** and **WeChat**?

Actually requirement is to send sms using WhatsApp and WeChat (Free sms).

Comment: refer http://developers.wechat.com/wechatapi

Comment: @Shink Thank you , I all ready Got This Sdk actually I need some tutorial how to integrate it programmatically ?

Comment: For sending messages using Whats and we chat you need to use Api of them and authentication.

Comment: there is no api for whatsapp ... u have to send Intent to it

Comment: @Mann Yes , I know there is no API .. I want to no any idea how to send programmatically by choosing any from whats app and we chat ?

Comment: THere are so many answers u got .....atlest check them out..?

Comment: @SubhalaxmiNayak : I am getting this Error : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.akm.whatsapp/com.akm.whatsapp.WhatsActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SENDTO typ=text/plain pkg=com.whatsapp (has extras) } ....... also whats app is in my device

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I got the Solution.. Here I am posting the answer so that it may help other people who may have same doubt..

For Share through any application...

```
public void sendAppMsg(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    String text = " message you want to share..";
    // change with required  application package  

    intent.setPackage("PACKAGE NAME OF THE APPLICATION");
    if (intent != null) {
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);//
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, text));
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, "App not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Note : change ***PACKAGE NAME OF THE APPLICATION** as per your requirement like

Example : USE

```
//Whatsapp
    intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");`

//Linkedin
    intent.setPackage("com.linkedin.android");

//Twitter    
    intent.setPackage("com.twitter.android");

//Facebook
    intent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");

//GooglePlus
    intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
```

Comment: For WeChat what will be the uri?

Comment: @AnshumanBorah use    intent.setPackage("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tencent.mm&hl=en");

Comment: @SubhalaxmiNayak I tried using intent.setPackage("com.tencent.mm"); It works but it open dialog with two option "WeChat" & "WeChat Favorites". Is it possible to open WeChat directly

Comment: Yes this is the same link for  WeChat Tencent   and both are same only.. check in playstore .

Comment: this would just open whatsApp, what if you want to send to particular contact directly, without tapping on contact.

Comment: If I want to share a file with one particular contact without tapping on contact?

Comment: I have FB app and I have not logged-in, then what is the behavior when you try to send msg from FB package?

Answer (score 15):

This should help to send message using whatsapp:

```
public void sendWhatsAppMsg() {

    Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    waIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String text = "testing message";
    waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    if (waIntent != null) {
        waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);//
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, text));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

}
```

Comment: @SubhalaxmiNayak No dear, sorry :(

Comment: How can I attach emoticons to the message?  
What are emoticons codes?

Comment: @CostaMirkin no much idea. But check [this](https://github.com/cblunt/android-emoticon-edittext-spike) and [this](http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2011/08/how-to-add-smileyemojis-in-edittext.html)

Comment: Is there anyway to specify a recipient?

Comment: Best solution to share on whatsapp. +1

Comment: Works great when WhatsApp is installed, but when it's not installed the screen dims and I get the message "No apps can perform this action." centered in the screen with the test message showing at the top of the screen.

Comment: What on earth do the View passed as param do? Its unused

Comment: intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text); does't work anymore. use the text in the url like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46683818/7147289

Answer (score 15):

To send direct message to any whatsapp user use following code :

```
private void sendMessageToWhatsAppContact(String number) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    try {
        String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + number + "&text=" + URLEncoder.encode(CommonStrings.SHARING_APP_MSG, "UTF-8");
        i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        if (i.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this code. It works but it's not exactly 'sending' it. It entered the text and now the user need to press 'send' button manually. Is it possible to just directly send it without waiting for the user to press the 'send' button?

Comment: I needed same functionality you are asking.. but didn’t find any way to send it directly..

Comment: I posted the same comment for a similar answer in a different post and they replied that it is due to security concerns of whatsapp that they don't allow it. I find it reasonable. Imagine some unknown app using your service to send messages without the interference of user. But I'm sure it might still be possible if we can simulate a touchevent on screen. However, it IS possible to directly send the message using the usual message app without waiting for user's approval.

Comment: Google has effectively revoked SEND_SMS permission from all but default SMS apps. Am I wrong that this approach (sending through WhatsApp, say) would be a work-around?

Comment: @NehaK Hi did you get the answer for this ? using this code opening app but not sending directly

Answer (score 2):

you can try one of these two solutions they worked for me.

reference: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/?category=5245251

```
private void openWhatsApp(String countryCode, String mobile) {
    String customerPhoneNumber = String.format("%s%s", countryCode, mobile);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + customerPhoneNumber);
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

    if(sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) == null){
        showDialogMessage("you should install whatsapp.");
        return;
    }

    startActivity(sendIntent);
}

or

private void openWhatsApp(String countryCode, String mobile) {
    String customerPhoneNumber = String.format("%s%s", countryCode, mobile);
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
// you can remove this part ("&text=" + "your message")
    String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + customerPhoneNumber + "&text=" + "your message"; 
    sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));

    if(sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) == null){
        showDialogMessage("you should install whatsapp.");
        return;
    }

    startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

Comment: Good answer! Now consider adding some info as to why it works :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest example that I get

```
/**
 * sends message to the specific application
 * @param text The message that user wants to send
 * @param view is the activity view of the application
 */
public void sendMessage(String text, View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.setPackage("com.example.appname");//For whatsapp you can use com.whatsapp
    if (intent !=null){
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        Snackbar.make(this, "Application not found.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```